# I'm trying to create a function that toggles between a 24 hour clock and a 12 hour clock using Boolean expressions

Tags: c++, function, boolean, swap

In a program that I am creating, I need to be able to toggle an option from the main menu to change from a 24 hour clock to a 12 hour clock and vice versa. I understand that I need to swap bool values in order to create a toggle, but I have no idea how to do so. Here is the function below:

```
void printTime(int h, int m, bool mode)
{
if (mode = 0)
{
    mode = 1;
    cout << "24-hour mode turned on" << endl;
}
else
{
    mode = 0;
    cout << "12-hour mode turned on" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Use `==` in C/C++ to test for equality. `=` is for assignment.

Comment: Also you are just changing a local variable, it will not affect any outer scope. Could you explain your intention better?

Comment: In the program, I need this function to affect the time display with changes in time (+ or - time), such that if the 24 hour mode is toggled, the time will read in 24 hours, while if the 12 hour mode is toggled, the time will read in a 12 hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change any variable outside your function's scope you should pass a reference.

```
void printTime(int h, int m, bool& mode)
{
    mode = !mode; //Toggle mode
    std::cout << (mode ? "24" : "12") << "-hour mode turned on" << std::endl;
}
```

Then it can change a value in a different scope;

```
int main()
{
    bool mode24 = true;
    printTime(2, 4, mode24); //changes mode24 to false
    printTime(2, 4, mode24); //changes mode24 back to true

    return 0;
}
```